# ¿Alternativa a la función STRING_SPLIT, para separar valores unidos con coma a filas?

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

Estoy usando la función STRING_SPLIT para generar filas de un valor escalar @ValueDatos VARCHAR(512) = "Uno, Dos, Tres" de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi base de desarrollo funciona perfecto pero en producción no puedo ejecutarla debido a que no puedo alterar el COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL de la base de datos. Igualmente quisiera aprender una alternativa de hacer esto sin usar una funcion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen varias alternativas, y todas disponen de su complejidad.

1. **XML**

En la primera parte, se separa cada uno de los items, haciendo un replace para convertir el separador en un varchar que contenga los datos y entre ellos vemos los elementos xml.

[image: Primera parte]

```
DECLARE @ValueDatos varchar(512) = 'Uno, Dos, Tres';
Declare @splitSeparator varchar(1) = ',';

DECLARE @X XML;
   SELECT @X = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' 
       + REPLACE(@ValueDatos, @splitSeparator, '</s><s>') + '</s></r>');

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
     FROM @X.nodes('/r/s') T(c);
```

Luego, como ya es un xml, se consulta utilizando xQuery.

Inconvenientes: El origen de los datos no puede contener "<>", ya que te devolvería un error tipo Análisis de XML. carácter no válido en nombre completo.

2. **DelimitedSplit8K**

Hay mucha controversia en foros especializados con esta función creada por Jeff Moden, sobre si sus análisis de rendimiento son exagerados o preparados para una ejecución en la que la misma salga beneficiada, pero lo que es seguro, es que funciona muy bien y es muy eficiente.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Ahora para utilizarla

```
DECLARE @ValueDatos varchar(512) = 'Uno, Dos, Tres';
Declare @splitSeparator varchar(1) = ',';

Select * from
    dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K](@ValueDatos, @splitSeparator);
```

[Delimited Split 8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

3. **Combinación de funciones.**

Ahora utilizaremos una combinación de dos funciones "magistrales". La primera creada por [Itzik Ben-Gan](https://tsql.solidq.com/SourceCodes/GetNums.txt), es muy usable para muchas otras cosas, que nos devuelve una columna de los números que hay entre los definidos como parámetros.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- © Itzik Ben-Gan, SolidQ
-- For more, see 5-day Advanced T-SQL Course:
-- http://tsql.solidq.com/t-sql-courses/
----------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetNums', N'IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
    L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)),
    L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
             FROM L5)
  SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n
  FROM Nums
  ORDER BY rownum;
GO
```

[image: Ejemplo]

Y la segunda, que no puedo poner el enlace de su autor, básicamente porque lo desconozco, pero se apoya en esta primera.

```
-- Erland's split_me
Create Function [dbo].[ufn_inline_split_me]
(
@param nvarchar(MAX), 
@delimiter nchar(1) = N','
)
RETURNS table AS
RETURN (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n) AS pos,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),
    SUBSTRING(@param, n,
    CHARINDEX(@delimiter, 
        @param + CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), 
    @delimiter), n) - n)))) 
    AS Value
FROM
    dbo.GetNums(1, LEN(@param))
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @delimiter) 
   + @param, n, 1) 
    = @delimiter
);
```

Ahora con las dos funciones tipo tabla, su consumo, sería:

```
DECLARE @ValueDatos varchar(512) = 'Uno, Dos, Tres';
Declare @splitSeparator varchar(1) = ',';

Select * from
    dbo.[ufn_inline_split_me](@ValueDatos, @splitSeparator);
```

[image: Resultado]

Resumen:

Aunque hay otras maneras, estas tres son muy buenas en rendimientos, no utilizan cursores,  no están limitadas a un numero finito de elementos y tampoco están limitadas a valores escalares. Las tres permiten tratar columnas como conjuntos con el operador apply.

**Nota adicional:** Qué no quieras utilizar funciones, por algún motivo específico, no quiere decir, que no puedas reformar una función para utilizar el mismo código directamente en tus desarrollos.

Answer (score 1):

### --Otra opción, aunque muy cavernícola pero otra opción al fin de cuentas:

/* Función para sustituir el uso del String_Split (Con SqlServer 2019)

```
Ejemplo de ejecución:

    Select * from dbo.fn_String_Split('Uno, Dos, Tres')
    
    ...y debe regresar algo como la siguiente tabla:

            Valor
            ---------       <--Sin ésto, claro!
            Uno
            Dos
            Tres
```

*/

Create Or Alter Function dbo.fn_String_Split( @ValueDatos VarChar(512) )
Returns  @TablaDatos Table (Valor VarChar(512))

AS

Begin
Declare
@Delimitador        Char(1) = ',',
@Desde              Int,
@Hasta              Int,
@Valor              VarChar(512)

```
While LEN(@ValueDatos) > 0
    Begin
        Set @Hasta = CHARINDEX(@Delimitador,@ValueDatos)
        If @Hasta > 0
            Begin
                /* Cuando hay delimitadores */
                Set @Valor = Substring(@ValueDatos, 1, @Hasta - 1)              /* Extrae el valor hasta un caracter antes de donde está el delimitador */
                Set @Desde = @Hasta + 1
                Set @ValueDatos = LTrim(SUBSTRING(@ValueDatos, @Desde, 512 ))   /* Conserva el string remanente sin procesar. Si quedan menos de 512 caracteres no hay problema */
            End
        Else
            Begin
                /* Cuando ya no haya delimitadores, se toma el último valor */
                Set @Valor = @ValueDatos                                        /* Toma el último valor ya que no hay delimitadores a la derecha */
                Set @ValueDatos = ''                                            /* Elimina los valores restantes para terminar el ciclo (While) */
            End

        /* Guarda el valor en un registro de la tabla */
        Insert Into @TablaDatos Values (@Valor)
    End

Return
```

End